# how to plot Fourier transform of several functions in the same plot

Tags: matlab, plot, transform, fft

I want to plot the fourier transform of a function. I wrote down this:

```
t=0:10
g=-1*(exp(-t)+t-1);
g1=fft(g);
x=-2:0.01:2;
plot(x,abs(g1))
```

It turned out no plot and there is no errors reported. May I ask where the errors are?
Thank you.

Comment: Your vectors aren't the same length.

Comment: You create your fft from `t`, which contains 11 values and then plot it over `x`, which contains 401 values. You have three possible solutions: plotting `abs(g1)` over `t`, calculating `abs(g1)` from `x` or interpolating `abs(g1)` over `x`.